# How can I open a .py file from another file in a separate console?

Tags: python, import, console

How can I open one python file from another in a separate console window. I have tried using `import file`, but this runs it in the same console as the original program.

Comment: please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

You want to execute another python instance for that.
Create a list where arg[0] is the python executable path (`sys.executable`).
This is like running the Python script from a command prompt or bash shell.

```
import subprocess, sys
script_name = 'my_other_script.py'
# set arg1, arg2, etc. to match the script arguments
cmd_line[sys.executable, script_name, arg1, arg2]
subprocess.check_call(cmd_line)
```